# UINavigationController supportedInterfaceOrientations: category vs swizzle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c-category

I'm using a tabBarController with multiple UINavigationControllers in my iPhone app, and now I want to add support for rotation (on some view controllers, not all). I know I need to implement the supportedInterfaceOrientation method for my UIViewControllers.

When the device is rotated, the supportedInterfaceOrientation is called on the UINavigationController, but I need it be called on my viewControllers. What's the best way to do this?

- I've seen some people create a category on UINavigationController that overrides supportedInterfaceOrientation to query the child viewControllers. But I know that Apple frowns upon using Categories to override methods. (I've implemented it like this, and it works fine, but I want to ensure the app continues to work with future version of iOS.)
- What about using method swizzling?
- Subclass UINavigationController?

Any suggestions appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use *iOS 6+* I would suggest subclassing `UINavigationController` and overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

Something similar to:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
  return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need subclass anything. Just add notification observer in every class that should react to orientation changes

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenOrientationChanged) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Whilst this will give you a notification when changing orientation, what it will not do is restrict the rotation of the device to certain orientations which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: You are right. But my variant is more flexible so it also could be useful for author. Also subclassing UINavigationController will require more code to write then subscribing and processing notification.